# Node/Express - res.status().send() only sends the status but does not send an object

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, fetch

I am having an issue with a route in my backend where `res.status().send()` will only send the client the status code, but it will not send the client the object located inside of `send()`.

Here is my code (redacted all code but the problem for brevity):

```
exports.user_signup = (req, res) => {
  const { body } = req;
  const { companyName, password, email } = body;

  User.find({ email: email }, (err, previousUsers) => {
    if (err) {
      return res.status(400).send({
        message: "There was an issue signing up."
      });
    } else if (previousUsers.length > 0) {
      return res.status(403).send({
        message: "Records show this email is linked to another account."
      });
    }
}
```

When I make my `fetch request` from the client, the response only returns the `status code` from the server, but nowhere in the response is the object in the `send()` method on the server. Just spitballing, I threw  `res.status(200).json(object)` at it to send the object as `json` to no avail.

Here is my `fetch request from the client:

```
  fetch("http://localhost:3000/users/accounts/", {
    method: "post",
    headers: {
      Accept: "application/json",
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(userData)
  }).then(response => console.log(response));
}
```

To show what response I am getting, I purposely posted some form data from the client to the route that would throw the 403 error, and this is the response I get in the browser console:

```
Response {type: "basic", url: "http://localhost:3000/users/accounts/", redirected: false, status: 403, ok: false, …}
```

So I am able to successfully send the status back from the route to the client, however I can not for the life of me figure out why `send()` does not send the object along with it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `body` of the response that comes back from `fetch()` is a `ReadableStream`.  You need to process it to turn it into something usable.  Normally you would call `response.json()` to parse it as a JSON object:

```
fetch("http://localhost:3000/users/accounts/", {
    method: "post",
    headers: {
        Accept: "application/json",
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(userData)
})
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(response => console.log(response));
}
```

Comment: Boom, this was exactly it. Thanks for the quick and insightful response.

Comment: Boom is my favorite reaction.